# Counting unique values based on two columns with repeated rows, R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, count, data.table

I have an R data frame with the following format:

```
column1    column2
NA         NA
1          A
1          A
1          A
NA         NA
NA         NA
2          B
2          B
NA         NA
NA         NA
3          A
3          A
3          A

df = structure(list(column1 = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 3L, 3L, 3L), column2 = c(NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, NA, "B", 
"B", NA, NA, "A", "A", "A")), .Names = c("column1", "column2"
), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

If the row in one column has an `NA`, the other column has an `NA`. 
The numerical value in `column1` describes a unique group, e.g. rows 2-4 have the group `1`. The column `column2` describes the identity of this grouping. In this data frame, the identity is either `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`.

My goal is to tally the number of identities by group within the entire data frame: how many A groups there are, how many B groups, etc.

The correct output for this file (so far) is there are 2 A groups and 1 B group.

How would I calculate this?

At the moment, I would try something like this:

```
length(df[df$column2 == "B"]) ## outputs 2
```

but this is incorrect. If I combined `column1` and `column2`, took only unique values 1A, 2B, 3A, I guess I could count how many times each label from `column2` occurs?

(If it's easier, I'm happy to use `data.table` for this task.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rle` for runs and `table` for tabulation:

```
table(rle(df$column2)$values)

# A B 
# 2 1
```

See `?rle` and `?table` for details.

Or, if you want to take advantage of `column1` (which is derived from `column2`):

```
table(unique(df)$column2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm struggling with how to access the values for this table. `(table(rle(df$column2)$values))$values` and `(table(rle(df$column2)$values))$A` both don't work.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang `rle` returns an object with $values and $lengths, but most R objects to not have this structure. If you do `res <- table(rle(df$column2)$values)`, it will be a named vector. You can access the names like `names(res)` or the values with `res` directly or `unname(res)`. This should be documented in the Value field of `?table` and `?rle`.

Answer (score 4):

The 'dplyr' package has simple functions for this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.) & !duplicated(.)) %>% 
  group_by(column2) %>%
  summarize(count = n())
```

1. Filter out rows with NA
2. Filter out duplicated rows; these represent individuals in the same group
3. Group by the identity variable (column2)
4. Count the number of unique groups (column1)

Comment: group_by summarise n() can be shortened to count or tally, I think. Or shorten to `df %>% distinct %>% count(column2)` maybe.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

d <- df[!is.na(column1), list(n=.N), by=list(column2,column1)]
d <- d[, list(n=.N), by=list(column2)]
d
   column2 n
1:       A 2
2:       B 1
```

Or more concisely as a one-liner:

```
setDT(df)[!is.na(column1), .N, by = .(column2, column1)][, .N, by = column2]
```